# Key Code listening enter key for pass to next edit Text

Tags: android, listener, keycode

i have this block of code

```
@Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        {
            int b = v.getId();
            switch (v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.EditTextSurname:
                EditTextName.requestFocus();
                break;
            case R.id.EditTextName:
                // TODO pass to remark
                break;
            case R.id.EditTextRemark:
                // TODO Hide keyboard
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
```

I'm listenning to the enter key of my editText. And i want to pass on the next edit text when i press the enter key. But if on the //TODO pass to remark

I set

```
EditTextRemark.requestFocus();
```

I can see on debug that it passed on the first request focus and without clicking again enter it will pass to the next editText.
If anyone have a solution of an explication for me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i found the problem , you need to declare event Action down , ( the key has been pressed down ) or it will pass on the onkey for life.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.EditTextSurname:
                EditTextName.requestFocus();
                break;
            case R.id.EditTextName:
                EditTextRemark.requestFocus();
                break;
            case R.id.EditTextRemark:
                hideSoftKeyboard();
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
```